# Modal spinner InAppBrowser in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins

I'm curious about showing a modal spinner on top of InAppBrowser plugin window in iOS.

I tried different Cordova plugins like [SpinnerDialog](http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/paldom/spinnerdialog%20in%20iOS) and others, but they show spinner on top of InAppBrowser only on Android. On iOS spinner is hidden under InAppBrowser window itself.

I know that InAppBrowser for iOS has it's own implementation of spinner, but we need exactly modal spinner - one which blocks the screen interaction until page finishes to load.

Answer (score 0):

Quick update: as long as I haven't received any response from the community, I implemented my own version of InAppBrowser with modal embedded spinner in it =)

Comment: Why don't you share your solution here then?

Comment: @orkoden I think that it will be more useful to contribute to plugin source code itself, than post here.